# How can I convert a .wav file to a mathematical function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Hi I am very new to this and I am not sure if this is the right forum to post this question.

Recently, I have recorded a combination of sounds in the form of a .WAV file. I want to identify the mathematical function that represents the sound that I have recorded. How can I do this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like StackOverflow question

Comment: You could use Fourier transform to try to write as a sum of trig functions.

Comment: @csch2 I'm not sure you'd be able to do that with raw data from a .wav file. I'm with Alex on this one that this question should probably be on one of the computer science/programming forums.

Comment: ... but unless the sound is quite simple and periodic,  you will need hundreds or thousands of terms to approximate it closely.

Comment: Close vote: more suitable on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure how .wav files are actually encoded but it is almost certainly the case that it already is a function albeit in a different form, e.g., the data could be a casewise function of sound amplitude vs. time or function of frequency vs. Fourier/cosine/etc. transform coefficients. So imo the pressing questions are how you will implement your software and possibly how you will interpolate between individual samples.

Comment: Why closing? This is a practical question that asks how to use mathematical tools. You need to generate first a list of the recorded values (you need to know the sampling rate). And than using a function of Fourier Transform you get the frequencies values that summed to result the .wav

Comment: @Moti Because it's a question of software implementation, not general math. If the Asker extracts their data and *then* reaches a problem involving Fourier transforms, that will be appropriate but at this stage, it is just a question of handling the data.

Comment: He specifically asks WHAT IS THE MATHEMATICAL FUNCTION?

Comment: @Moti And? See my earlier comment. Finding the function is trivial. The only difficult part is extracting the data.

Comment: Converting a WAV file to some other format is indeed a programming task, not a mathematical task. But the first question you need to answer is *what other format for the sound data do you need*? The commenters above have assumed you are looking for some expression of the frequency function. But you haven't indicated that. So first. figure out exactly what it is you need to convert the wav file to, then post the question - with that vital information included - on a programming forum. Also decide what language you want to do it in.